# How to use my Linux computer's internet connection in Raspberry Pi through a router?

Tags: networking, ssh, pi-b

I have connected my desktop computer (running Ubuntu 16.04) to my Raspberry Pi through a router (ethernet connection).
My computer can access internet with USB tethering from my phone.
I can SSH to the Raspberry Pi, but it cannot connect to internet.

`ping google.com` says `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

`sudo apt update` says `Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'`.

How to forward my computer's internet connection to Raspberry Pi?

The router is only connected to the desktop and the Raspberry Pi.

**Update:**

I directly connected the Raspberry Pi to my computer through ethernet, and connected a monitor to the Pi. Then I ran `ifconfig` in the Pi to get its IP address (it was `10.42.0.38`, maybe this is the default?)

Then I sshed to the RPi from my desktop, and now it is connected to the internet. However, this does not solve the issue when RPi is connected to a router and there is no way to connect a display.

Comment: This is a question about your computer (and router). The Pi will use any connection with DHCP.

Answer (score 6):

If you can ping an IP address (like 8.8.8.8) but not a URL, you have a problem with accessing a DNS server to look up names.

It's *really* hard to understand how your system is connected with the details you have provided but I'm hoping this helps you look in the right place.

(Sorry to use "Answer" but I don't have enough rep to "Comment")

Comment: Let's add some rep

Answer (score 0):

What you call a router is probably just an ethernet switch, which means it doesn't matter whether you connect your Pi to the linux computer through it or using a direct cable. The linux computer can be configured as a DHCP server and NAT router for the Pi, I'm pretty sure this can be done using the network manager GUI so you don't have to tweak config files. Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#GUI_Method_via_Network_Manager_.28Ubuntu_14.04.2C_16.04.29 as a starting point.

Comment: Where is the problem with the Raspberry Pi you solved with your answer?

Comment: Where the actual problem is is not really clear from the description. I prefer to point to possible things to look at instead of downvoting due to wrong SE site. Getting networking right is a common issue for Raspi users, so it might be helpful to others having similar issues.